Why parent process is active when not using wait function?
I am using pipes to display file contents. When I comment the wait command (in the last part of the parent process), I expect to see the parent process in the ps command's output (after a while, because reading is completed and I am still browsing output generated by child process), but I see both parent and child processes in the output.
The following code shows argv1 content. After building the program (for example xpager) it should be executed as xpager filename.
My platform is Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define BUFSIZE 8192
#define PPAGER  "/usr/bin/less"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pid_t   pid;
    int eerrno, n;
    int in, pfd[2];
    char    buf[BUFSIZE];
    char    *pager, *argv0;


    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("usage: %s <pathname>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    if ( (in = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)) < 0) {
        eerrno = errno;
        printf("Open error. %s(%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
        exit(eerrno);
    }

    if ( pipe(pfd) < 0) {
        eerrno = errno;
        printf("pipe error. %s(%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
        exit(eerrno);
    }


    pid = fork();
    switch (pid) {
        case -1:
            eerrno = errno;
            printf("fork error. %s(%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
            exit(eerrno);

        case 0:
            close(pfd[1]);
            close(in);
            if (STDIN_FILENO != pfd[0]) {
                if (dup2(pfd[0], STDIN_FILENO) < 0) {
                    eerrno = errno;
                    printf("dup2 error. %s(%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
                    exit(eerrno);
                }
                close(pfd[0]);
            }
            if ((pager=getenv("PPAGER")) == NULL)
                pager = PPAGER;
            if ((argv0=strrchr(pager, '/')) != NULL)
                argv0++;
            else
                argv0=pager; 
            execlp(pager, argv0, argv[1], (char *)0);
        default:
            close(pfd[0]);
            while((n=read(in, buf, BUFSIZE)) > 0) {
                if (write(pfd[1], buf, n) < 0) {
                    eerrno = errno;
                    printf("write errno. %s(%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
                    kill (pid, 9);
                    exit(eerrno);
                }
            }
            if (n < 0) {
                eerrno = errno;
                printf("read error. %s(%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
                kill(pid, 9);
                exit(eerrno);
            }
            close(pfd[1]);
        //  wait(NULL);
    }

    exit(0);
}

For easier reading, summarized code is as follow:
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define BUFSIZE 8192
#define PPAGER  "/usr/bin/less"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        pid_t   pid;
        int     n,in, pfd[2];
        char    buf[BUFSIZE];
        char    *pager, *argv0;

        in = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
        pipe(pfd);

        pid = fork();
        switch (pid) {
                case 0:
                        close(pfd[1]);
                        dup2(pfd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
                        pager = PPAGER;
                        argv0="less";
                        execlp(pager, argv0, argv[1], (char *)0);
                default:
                        close(pfd[0]);
                        while ((n=read(in, buf, BUFSIZE)) > 0)
                                write(pfd[1], buf, n);
                        close(pfd[1]);
                //      wait(NULL);
        }
        return(0);
   }


exit(0); don't use this at the end of main(). Either return 0 or do nothing

It is another question. But as I know, there no difference between return and exit at the end of main

When I execute this, albeit on macOS rather than Ubuntu, as soon as the parent exits, the child also exits, and there is no opportunity to execute ps and see them. Are you sure you are executing the code shown in the question? Also, did you intend not to have a break; before default:?

You should execute ps in another session

Since you provide argv[1] as an argument to the pager program, it won't be reading standard input.  Your parent process would get blocked writing to the pipe if the file is big enough (more than 64 KiB).

But when the pager (child process) reached to end of file, the parent has been readed and writed whole data and there shold not be any blocking (Its is my understanding)

How big is the named file?

I tested it with both 10 bytes and 1MB files. The results are the same

How do you start the parent?
I just wondering, could the parent process (in ps output) be a zombie?

No, I see both parent and child process as normal process. Did you executed the code?

Yes, I tried it with commands: gcc -Wall -Wextra test.c -o test and  ./test ./test.txt ; ps -f
Child existed with PPID=1.

In a comment, you said "no difference between return and exit at the end of main".  That's not strictly true, but the differences are subtle and it rarely makes a difference.  Nevertheless, it is inaccurate.  For example, if your main() contains char buffer[1024]; setvbuf(stdout, buffer, _IOFBF, sizeof(buffer));, using return 0 could lead to undefined behaviour if stdout needs to be flushed, whereas exit(0); would be fine.  But this is obscure!

You have execlp(pager, argv0, argv[1], (char *)0); followed immediately by a default: label in the switch statement.  If any of the exec*() family of functions succeeds, it does not return.  If it returns, it failed (so there's no need to test the return value).  But you should allow for the possibility of failure — usually by printing an error message on stderr and exiting with a non-zero status, but YMMV.  Note that error messages should normally be reported on stderr rather than stdout — your code writes a lot of error messages to stdout.'

Although kill(pid, 9) is a sure kill (9 is equivalent to SIGKILL), it is not a good idea, especially when the target program has adjusted the terminal settings as less will have done.  Some modern shells may reset the terminal themselves, but traditionally, killing programs like vim or less left the terminal in a weird state.

You should consider using the err(3) functions for error reporting.  Or you could use my error reporting code, which is available in my SOQ (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files stderr.c and stderr.h in the src/libsoq sub-directory.

Get rid of the filename argument when calling the pager in the child process. When it's not given a filename, it will read from its standard input by default, and stdin has been redirected to the pipe:
So change
execlp(pager, argv0, argv[1], (char *)0);

to
execlp(pager, argv0, (char *)0);


I mistakely press down vote. If you edit your answer, I can correct it (I apologize you)

@tahzibi.jafar tweaked some wording

I believe the problem is that you are passing the wrong arguments to the exec call. You are setting up the pipes correctly, redirecting the reading end of the child's pipe to stdin, but you then pass argv[1] to the child (which is the less binary).
less takes a file to read from as its first argument, so when you pass argv[1] the process just reads directly from that file instead of from the pipe you set up. This causes less to appear to behave correctly, and the parent process gets blocked trying to write to the pipe, since nobody is reading from it.
Try passing "/dev/stdin" instead of argv[1] to exec and see if that solves your problem. /dev/stdin is a pseudo-file on linux referring to the input stream. Since this is the case, you will also need to pass -f to less to force it to display this file.
Note that you will most likely still see the parent process running, since less is only reading from the file as needed, as stated in its man page.
Edit: Instead of redirecting the pipe to stdin, you can also pass the pipe's file descriptor directly to the process. All open file descriptors can be found at /dev/fd/. Here you will find the files 0, 1 and 2 for stdin, stdout and stderr respectively. Any currently opened file descriptors (e.g. files, pipes etc) can also be found here.
The pipe's file descriptor is stored in the integer variable you defined (pfd). So instead of redirecting to stdin, you can do:
char pipe_fd[32];
sprintf(pipe_fd, "/dev/fd/%d", pfd[0]);
execlp(pager, argv0, "-f", pipe_fd, (char *)0);


The effect is the same.
In both cases, when less reaches the EOF, the parent will terminate and less will also be shut down by the the init process (parent of all processes on the system).

Just leave out the filename argument entirely, and less will read from stdin by default.

less doesn't exit when it reaches EOF. It allows the user to page back and forth in the file, and doesn't exit until they enter a command like q.

@Barmar that is true, I did not think of that, I will update my answer. When I played around with the code, less seemed to exit when the pipe was closed, but perhaps this was because the parent process exited and thus less was also killed by the system

Ah, I see — the 'which' was mildly ambiguous, and I misinterpreted it.  I've removed my comment and will soon remove this one too.  I think your response to my deleted comment should go.
